# &:hover not working for element inside hovered element with SCSS

Tags: css, sass

```
.sub-link {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      padding-left: 8px;
      min-height: 50px;
      &__title {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-left: 8px;
      }
      &__arrow {
        margin-left: auto;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        transition: transform 0.3s;
      }
      &:hover > &__arrow {
        transform: translateX(4px);
      }
    }
```

When I write this code .sub-link__arrow image is not being affected on .sub-link:hover.

```
.sub-link {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      padding-left: 8px;
      min-height: 50px;
      &__title {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-left: 8px;
      }
      &__arrow {
        margin-left: auto;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        transition: transform 0.3s;
      }
    }
    .sub-link:hover .sub-link__arrow {
      transform: translateX(4px);
    }
```

But when I write it in normal css it works, I don't understand why SCSS version not works. I am 100% sure I am writing the syntax right.

Comment: Because you have `&:hover > &__arrow` in the scss example, which means it'll only take affect if its a direct descendent. I'm guessing the `.sub-link__arrow` element isn't an immediate child of the root element?

Comment: it does not work event without arrow (>),and yes it is direct child of .sub-link,there must be some ordering problems with SCSS then